# Use Nokogiri to scrape a website that uses Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

For a project for a class, I am trying to scrape a website. From this website,

```
https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/attractions/
```

I'm trying to pull all attraction URLs. For example, for the first attraction in the list, I'm trying to grab this url:

```
https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/attractions/epcot/mission-space-advanced-training-lab/
```

Since the website uses Javascript, I'm having a hard time getting the urls using Nokogiri and selectors. Class names don't seem to work, and my attempt returns a different url than I'm trying to snag. The best I have is:

```
index_page.css("ul").children.css("li").each do |container|
```

but container returns the incorrect urls. It was suggested that I use the gem watir, but neither I nor my instructors can figure out how to use it.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to learn rails to use `watir`. You can use vanilla ruby, just like you are doing currently with `nokogiri`.

Comment: Also, if you want to "cheat", here's something you could do... Just download `https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/en_GB/sitemap.xml` and grab all URLs containing `/attractions/` or whatever :)

Comment: I did this site with mechanize once but it was a maze of json. I suggest selenium/watir/headless chrome instead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are loading the page using something like `open-uri`. The site is a little odd in that the first request to https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/attractions/ does not return the attractions list. That list is returned by a subsequent XMLHttpRequest to the same url. So you probably aren't seeing the results in the content at all.

You can simulate the XMLHttpRequest (and do a lot of other stuff) by using a gem like [mechanize](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/). Here's a working example that gets those attraction urls:

```
require 'mechanize'

url = 'https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/attractions/'
mech = Mechanize.new;

# make an XMLHttpRequest to get the page (returns attraction list)
mech.get(url, [], nil, { 'x-requested-with' => 'XMLHttpRequest' }) do |page|
  page.search('ul.finderList li').each do |attraction|
    name = attraction.at_css('h2.cardName').content
    link = attraction.at_css('a')['href']
    puts "#{name}: #{link}"
  end
end
```

The `page.search` method returns a Nokogiri node set, so you can use Nokogiri methods for further processing.

Comment: Nice work you beat me to it. :) [Example of the above](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/mechanizePageScrape)